# Allow users to view and download files from server

Tags: php, web, download

I'd like users to be able to view files (I need to research this further, PDF/doc viewer, vid player etc) on the site before choosing to download them.  Any suggestions on suitable methods?

The main question though is allowing them to download files.

I read on another SO post that this:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

is suitable however I'll be pulling the file name from the database.  I'm thinking of using a standard download page so that `download.php?filename=thisFileToDownload` can pass the filename along.

The other issue is that there are different file types such as images, videos, excel, docs and pdfs etc etc.  Are there any problems that I might run into with this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: what happens if i go to `download.php?filename=/etc/passwd`

Comment: The filename has a unique id attached so hopefully it won't be that simple for an average joe to pop the name of the file into the url.  Typing the above into another page that empliys the same technique returns a message of 
Message:

etcpasswd

Comment: `Are there any problems that I might run into with this?`... perhaps if you expect seeking on video